# Use of "did" in English grammar

Tags: meaning, difference

Is it correct to say

> When you reached home.

or

> When did you reach home?

As per my knowledge,

> When you reached home (When you reach home you will find something)
>   When did you reach home (when you reached home in past)

Is that correct?

Comment: The topic is too broad. But just to answer your concern - If it's a question, prefer the format - *When did you reach home?* However, *When you reached home?* is also correct (and mean same) but is informal, generally used in a day-to-day conversation.

Comment: As a general note, I have noticed many of my coworkers from India also say, "*reached home*" which is not wrong, just not idiomatic.  Americans, at least, will generally talk about *getting home*.  For example: *When did you get home?  When you get home you'll find a letter for you on the desk*

Comment: It _is_ idiomatic, in Indian English. Actually, in Indian English, "I reached" is often used to indicate one finished a planned trip.

Answer (score 1):

```
When you reach home
```

is not a question, but rather a part of a sentence. Something like

```
"When you reach home, you will find your lunch served on the table."
```

The latter, i.e. `"When did you reach home?"`is a question, asking when that person reached home. Also, please note, it is 

"When you **reach** home,......"
 and not "When you **reached** home"

Answer (score 0):

A question headed by a *Wh-* interrogative always requires an **auxiliary** verb in the second position; this is followed by the **subject**, then the **lexical verb** in its infinitive form.

If the 'answer' form of your question involves an auxiliary verb, you use that in the second position ...

> [**A**: I **can be** there tomorrow.] ← **Q**: When <sub>aux</sub>**can** <sub>subj</sub>you <sub>inf</sub>**be** there?

If it does not involve an auxiliary verb, you use *do* as a ‘generic’ auxiliary in the second position ...

> [**A**: I **reached** home yesterday.] ← **Q**: When <sub>aux</sub>**did** <sub>subj</sub>you <sub>inf</sub>**reach** home?

As others have noted in the Comments, *reach home* is an unusual way of expressing this thought in Standard Englishes; it’s not incorrect, but we usually use *get* (colloquial) or *arrive* (formal):

> When did you get home?
>   When did you arrive home?